# Backup and restore Subversion user permissions

Tags: backup, permissions, svn

We use `svnsync` to create fully functional backup servers, and we have a script to do so.

However if we wanted to create a new backup server, we have to copy the `htpasswd` and `groups.conf` file across (that is not hard) and (after running `svnsync`) manually assign the user/group to repositories. Also, if we change the assignment in the main server, there is no easy way to apply that change to all backup servers.

Since we have 50+ projects and 30+ users this is a boring and error-pond exercise. Are there any tools that can help us to backup and restore those automatically? We are using VisualSVN under Windows, so it is better to have solutions in Windows scripts, not shell scripts.